# Inline div not properly aligned

Tags: css, inline

Please see JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MU2y2/
The bottom divs are not properly aligned, but i can't find why.
I think this must have to do with the display inline-block. However, there is no top-margin

```
<div class="kaders">
<div class="rij">
    <div class="kader" href="http://www.checkjekamer.nl/check/huurZelfstandig">
        <h1>Zelfstandig</h1>
        <p>Check hier je kamer als je in <b>zelfstandige</b> woonruimte woont</p>
    </div>

    <div class="kader" href="http://www.checkjekamer.nl/check/huurOnzelfstandig">
        <h1>Onzelfstandig</h1>
        <p>Check hier je kamer als je in <b>onzelfstandige</b> woonruimte woont</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="rij">
    <div class="kader" href="http://www.checkjekamer.nl/check/huurToeslag">
        <h1>Huurtoeslag</h1>
        <p>Check hier de hoogte van je <b>huurtoeslag</b></p>
    </div>

    <div class="kader" href="http://www.checkjekamer.nl/check/brandveiligheid">
        <h1>Brandveiligheid</h1>
        <p>Check hier de <b>brandveiligheid</b> van je kamer</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);


body{
    font-family:Open Sans;
}

/*  background-color: #f7f7f7;
    color:#d10000;
*/

.kaders{
    text-align:center;  
}

.kader{
    cursor:pointer;
    display:inline-block;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    margin:10px;
    margin-top:0;
}

.rij{
    display:block;
    border:1px solid pink;
}

.kader h1{
    font-size:1.1em;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `vertical-align: text-top;` to your `.kader`

Read more about `vertical-align` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align)

```
.kader{
    cursor:pointer;
    display:inline-block;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    margin:10px;
    margin-top:0;
    vertical-align: text-top;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/MU2y2/2/)

Comment: Snap. (Well pretty much, I got in first ;) ) Since it was pretty much the same time and this is too correct... +1

Answer (score 2):

Add `vertical-align: top;` to `.kader`.

**CSS:**

```
.kader{
    cursor:pointer;
    display:inline-block;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    margin:10px;
    margin-top:0;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/MU2y2/1/)